# Output contents of HTML Element into console

Tags: javascript, html

I know only a little bit of JavaScript. I need to output in my terminal a message input by user in a html form, but my current JavaScript solution isn't displaying the right output.

**HTML**

```html
<h2 class="heading">Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>
<input name="myText" id="myText" type="text" placeholder="enter your message here">
<button id="btn" onclick="sendMail()">Send</button>
<script src="./server.js"></script>
```

**javascript**

```
console.log(document.getElementById('myText').innerText());
```

Comment: just fyi: The `innerText` property does not apply to `input` elements - they have a `value` attribute instead.

Comment: applying this ->> [var x=document.getElementById('myText').value;
console.log(x); ] gave me output terminal as      var x=document.getElementById('myText').value;
      ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\server.js:31:7)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean and how you used that code? You could `edit` your question and add this perhaps?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you wish to get the value from the text field when some sort of event occurs? Assign an event handler to the input element - like so:

```js
document.querySelector('input[name="myText"]').addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
  console.log(this.value)
})
```

```html
<h2 class="heading">Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>
<input name="myText" id="myText" type="text" placeholder="enter your message here">
<button id="btn" onclick="sendMail()">Send</button>
```

To assign an `event handler` to the `button`

```js
document.querySelector('button#btn').addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.previousElementSibling.value)
})
```

```html
<h2 class="heading">Send e-mail to someone@example.com:</h2>
<input name="myText" id="myText" type="text" placeholder="enter your message here">
<button id="btn">Send</button>
```

Comment: i am getting this as output terminal ->> document.querySelector('button#btn').addEventListener('click',function(e){      
^

ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: pls help me regarding that

Comment: `(C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\server.js` concerns me - are you running a webserver ( apache,iis,zope etc ) or is this being run from a local file?

Comment: i am using nodemon to run the js file on vs code terminal

Comment: I don't think I can offer guidance here as I have used neither and cannot visualise how this works ( or doesn't as the case may be ).

Answer (score 3):

Use this and you get the value inside input

```
document.getElementById('myText').value
```

Comment: ok, i edited my js code as-> var x=document.getElementById('myText').value;
console.log(x);      and my terminal output is ->  var x=document.getElementById('myText').value;
      ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\91725\Desktop\sending_mail\server.js:31:7)

Comment: the above solution is not working, I was trying to get the output for my <TextInput>. Please help me with working statement.

Comment: Make sure u declared the sendMail() function, or maybe u have others problems, on my pc this works

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery.

```
$(':input').keyup(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```